# find the vector $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and the constants $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $T(x,y,z) = (\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z )$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation, vectors

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by : $$T(x,y,z) = (x-y+4z,3x+2y-z,2x+y-z)$$

How can i find the vector $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and the constants $\lambda  \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $T(x,y,z) = (\lambda x, \lambda y, \lambda z )$, i stuck i don't know how to start this exercise , please help.

Comment: Hint: $T u = \lambda u$ is called an eigenvalue problem, with eigenvalue (german for "self value") $\lambda$ and eigenvector $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you don't know about eigenvalues, yet.

What you have to find are the numbers $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ for which a nonzero vector $(x,y,z)$ exists such that $T(x,y,z)=\lambda(x,y,z)$. Why nonzero? Because $(0,0,0)$ is good for any $\lambda$.

This is equivalent to saying
$$
\begin{cases}
x-y+4z=\lambda x\\
3x+2y-z=\lambda y\\
2x+y-z=\lambda z
\end{cases}
$$
or, which is the same,
$$
\begin{cases}
(1-\lambda)x-y+4z=0\\
3x+(2-\lambda)y-z=0\\
2x+y+(-1-\lambda)z=0
\end{cases}
$$
and this linear system has a nonzero solution if and only if the rank of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\lambda & -1 & 4\\
3 & 2-\lambda & -1\\
2 & 1 & -1-\lambda
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is less than $3$.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: then i need to find the characteristic polynomial then find its roots ?

Comment: @Knight So you do know about eigenvalues, don't you?

Comment: yes but for me its complicated understand when i need to apply this process , for example in books this process is for diagonalize a matrix and when i have a linear transformation like that i´m confused

Comment: @Knight The problem is to find $v\ne0$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$, for some $\lambda$. This is exactly the definition of eigenvector (and eigenvalue).

Comment: ok, thanxs for the explication really ty, im studying so hard this topics.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
T\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
=
A\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 4\\ 3 & 2 & -1\\ 2 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus we wish to compute the eigenvectors of $A$.
Do you know where to go from here?

Comment: yes from the canonical basis of R^3

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
T u = \lambda u \iff (T - \lambda E) u = 0
$$
where $T$ is the matrix form of your map $T$ and  $E$ is the unit / identity matrix with $E_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$.

$$
u \in \mbox{ker} (T - \lambda E)
$$

and you want a non-zero vector $u$, so you know the matrix $T - \lambda E$ can not be invertible.